# Make equinox verify bundles

Tags: java, osgi, eclipse-rcp, jaas, equinox

I want Eclipse RCP product to verify signatures of all it's bundles on startup. So I added these arguments to eclipse.ini:

```
-Dosgi.signedcontent.support=all
-Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=fail
```

I randomly changed signatures in several system and mine modules in plugins, but RCP app still loads and works without any prompt. So, seems verification does not take place.

**How can I make equinox verify all bundles?** Am I limited to use security manager for that (I don't want to turn it on, because of performance issues)?

Where can I find any documentation about equinox's bundle verification and security manager?

Comment: Could you be a bit more clear about what you actually did? "I randomly changed signatures in several system and mine modules in plugins." Do you mean you randomly changed the digests in the manifest and related files, while leaving the code itself intact? Or did the opposite?

Comment: I changed the digests, expecting to get some security exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes to eclipse.ini and got verification working. I haven't figured out which exact setting helped, so (for now) I use these:

```
...
-vmargs
-Dorg.osgi.framework.security=osgi
-Djava.security.policy=/test.policy
-Dosgi.signedcontent.support=all
-Dosgi.support.signature.verify=true
-Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=fail
-Dosgi.signedcontent.trust.engine=BundleTrustEngine
```

test.policy is *allow all* jaas policy:

```
grant {
permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Comment: Tested. Without "allow all" policy, equinox is not even launching: access denied to native and jar launcher. "org.osgi.framework.security=osgi" + "allow all" - bundles are not verified. Investigating for minimal set.

Comment: Strange. it works fine here. but the most important is that it's working now for you, so the question is settled.